# Visualforce: How to get the look of pagination buttons from a standard object like accounts to my custom visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, pagination

I have this code for the pagination buttons:

```
<apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom" html-align="left">
            <apex:commandButton id="firstpage" value="◄◄" reRender="details" action="{!FirstPage}" disabled="{!prev}" styleClass="first"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="previouspage" value="◄ Previous" reRender="details" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="nextpage" value="Next ►" reRender="details" action="{!next}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
            <apex:commandButton id="lastpage" value="►►" reRender="details" action="{!LastPage}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
        </apex:pageblockButtons>
```

It looks like this on the web:
[image]

I want to make it look like this, which is the pagination buttons used in listing all account records:
[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but not quite concrete enough for an answer. Given that, I think this is more appropriate as an answer.

I don't believe there's any OOB (out of the box) functionality you can use to accomplish this.

The standard pagination controls are closer to `<apex:commandLink>` than `<apex:commandButton>`. You may be able to include additional CSS to get the styling closer (removing the text color, hover changes, underline, change the cursor style, etc...) but it probably won't be perfect.

You may be able to use something like `<apex:outputText>` together with `<apex:actionSupport>` to accomplish the same thing as well.

You'll have to experiment with these to see if any work for you.